# Форматирование из .py в .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Я установил `pyinstaller` через `pip`. Ввёл команду: `pyinstaller --onefile -w -i "путь иконки" <name>.py`. Программа и вправду скомпилировалась в .exe файл, но при запуске программы возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался решить эту проблему с помощью интернета, но ничего дельного не нашёл. Visual C ++ у меня установлен и всё должно исправно работать. Но эта ошибка возникает.

На всякий случай:

Сам код: https://github.com/Bazili0/MECOde/blob/main/program

Изображение для иконки: https://ibb.co/gRPTS5Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-бы скомпилировать ваш код я прошёл семь кругов ада! У меня была такая же проблема! Вам нужно установить модуль auto-py-to-exe , команда - pip install auto-py-to-exe , затем запустить его по директории куда вы устанавливали Python - затем зайдите в папку Scripts и запустите файл auto-py-to-exe.py . Изучите программу. Выберите все необходимые параметры программы, когда программа успешно скомпилирует ваш код, не выходите из неё, когда перейдете в папку вывода, может быть ошибка исполнения файла. Переместите вашу программу куда вам угодно, готово! Но перед перемещением проверьте её работоспособность!

Comment: Вряд-ли это можно сравнить с кругами ада, почти из всех стеков надо так компилировать, это нормально

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное разьяснение